# Trying to run SQL script from VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, database-connection

I wish to run some VBA code that accesses the SQL Server, runs the SQL script, and returns the output.

My script works on a smaller SQL script, however when I run a SQL script that takes about 3 min 30 secs I get a:

> run time error '-2147217871 Query timeout expired.

This is my first time trying to do this so I am not fully aware of everything that is going on in my code.

Here is my the VBA code that I use:

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim objCmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim fld As ADODB.Field
Dim mssql As String
Dim row As Integer
Dim col As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset


'CREATE A STRING BY READING THE SQL FILE ROW BY ROW
mssql = ""

Dim hnd As Integer
hnd = FreeFile

'paste the place where the sql file is in here
Open "directory for my sql file" For Input As hnd

'loop sql file row by row and add each row to the string
Dim file_row As String
Do Until EOF(hnd)
    Line Input #hnd, file_row
    mssql = mssql & file_row & vbNewLine
Loop

Close #hnd


'Debug.Print mssql

oConn.ConnectionString = "driver={SQL Server};" & _
"server=myserver;uid=name;pwd=password;database=my database"

'-------------changing connection timeout and commandTimeout doesn't seem to help--------------'
oConn.ConnectionTimeout = 500
oConn.Open
objCmd.CommandTimeout = 500
objCmd.ActiveConnection = oConn

rs.Open mssql, oConn

If rs.EOF Then
    MsgBox "No matching records found."
    rs.Close
    oConn.Close
    Exit Sub
End If

Debug.Print "We made it"

rs.Close

oConn.Close
```

Comment: Try setting `.CommandTimeout = 0` (wait forever) and see if that changes anything.

Comment: I tried this, and it runs about 30 secs before same error pops up.

Comment: What's the "remote query timeout" setting on the database side?

Comment: The remote query timeout is above 1400

Comment: That was my last idea...

Comment: Don't know if you did this already or not: You need to set `.CommandTimeout` both for the connection (`oConn`) **AND** and the command (`objCmd`)

Comment: @statistical_student We use something similar. A couple of things I would do to test. 
1 - Hard code a simple "Select Top (1) from...." as the sql string in the VBA rather than refer to an external script. I've had problems with external script due to the first couple of lines of commented code etc
2 - If the connection and code works fine from step 1, add a breakpoint where you are looping through the external script. [mssql = mssql & file_row & vbNewLine]
In the immediate window do ?mssql which will output what the looping is creating.
?VariableName helps a lot in VBA.

Comment: Thanks for tips, I changed the code a bit and one thing I didn't think about was that my sql script had temp tables which caused a problem

This was fixed by setting "SET NOCOUNT ON " infront of my script (or rather mssql = "SET NOCOUNT ON ")

Now the script works.